# How to find correct size of action bar, status bar and navigation bar in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, statusbar, navigationbar

[image: Android ActionBar , StatusBar , NavigationBar , Window Size]

As you see in the picture , I have problem in functions that return size of Action Bar , Status Bar , Navigation Bar and Window Size :

My android phone has 1280*720 pixel resolution , The returned Value of Status Bar is 48px , Action Bar is 96px , Navigation Bar is 96px and default display height size 1184px (I found out that returns resolution except navigation bar height size  "1280-96 = 1184"  and in phones that hasn't soft navigation bar that returns the resolution height)
the problem is summation of action bar and status bar is 96+48 = 144
so we have 160-144 = 16px disappeared ! but I know the summation of status bar and action bar must be 160px, that's first problem

Second problem is when I touch Navigation Bar there is no touch sense (no position of touch in application ) but when I touch white space of application (main window , not action bar or status bar or navigation bar) and drag my finger on navigation bar , it has touch sense and return position of my finger on navigation bar !!!

I used these functions for getting data :

```
public int getNavigationBarHeight(){
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        return getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return 0;
}

public int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}

public Point getDisplaySize() {
    Display currentDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    currentDisplay.getSize(size);
    return size;
}

public boolean hasSoftNavigationBar() {
    Context context = getBaseContext();
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    int id = resources.getIdentifier("config_showNavigationBar", "bool", "android");
    if (Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic") || (id > 0 && resources.getBoolean(id)) ) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Note : I found out that getNavigationBarHeight() returns values for some phone that hasn't soft navigation bar , but when I am sure that phone has navigation bar with hasSoftNavigationBar() function , get NavigationBarHeight() has true value